# Remove top page number and section name in LegrandOrangeBook

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, books, book-design, legrandorangebook

Am using [LegrandOrangeBook](https://www.latextemplates.com/template/legrand-orange-book) book template. I would like to know how to remove the page numbers on the top headers and their corresponding section names. I want to have the page number in the centre of the footer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In file "structure.tex", replace the code with following, about at row 176.

```
\fancyhf{} % Clear default headers and footers
%\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\sffamily\normalsize\thepage} % Styling for the page number in the header
%\fancyhead[LO]{\rightmark} % Print the nearest section name on the left side of odd pages
%\fancyhead[RE]{\leftmark} % Print the current chapter name on the right side of even pages
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage} % Uncomment to include a footer
```